# How can I fix the layout of my site for mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I made here a simple ethereum directory site
you can view it here [black-bit.surge.sh](http://black-bit.surge.sh)

Im trying to fix the alyout for mobile- I want that that the category cards show up on mobile underneath each other and not only make it responisve.

Basically 1 category card should be 1 line

How can i do this?

```
You can view the full code on pastepin
```

https://pastebin.com/H9cUfanP

If you have a better idea for layout please also post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML Missing `viewport` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

[image]

> Bootstrap is developed mobile first, a strategy in which we optimize
>   code for mobile devices first and then scale up components as
>   necessary using CSS media queries. To ensure proper rendering and
>   touch zooming for all devices, add the responsive viewport meta tag to
>   your .

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag

**Starter template her:**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/